# Query to MySQL from c# returns System.Byte[]

Tags: c#, mysql, connection-string

I am using the below SP to return the value of Generated Insert statement and it works fine when executed in Query browser.

When i try to get the value from C#, it give's me "System.Byte[]" as return value. 
When i try to get the value from MySql query browser, it give's me return value as :

'insert into admindb.accounts values("54321","2","karthik2","karthik2","1");'

I guess the problem is with the single quotes of the returned value. Is it so ?

```
    DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `admindb`.`InsGen` $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `InsGen`(
in_db varchar(20),
in_table varchar(20),
in_ColumnName varchar(20),
in_ColumnValue varchar(20)
)
BEGIN

declare Whrs varchar(500);
declare Sels varchar(500);
declare Inserts varchar(2000);
declare tablename varchar(20);
declare ColName varchar(20);


set tablename=in_table;


# Comma separated column names - used for Select
select group_concat(concat('concat(\'"\',','ifnull(',column_name,','''')',',\'"\')'))
INTO @Sels from information_schema.columns where table_schema=in_db and table_name=tablename;


# Comma separated column names - used for Group By
select group_concat('`',column_name,'`')
INTO @Whrs from information_schema.columns where table_schema=in_db and table_name=tablename;


#Main Select Statement for fetching comma separated table values

 set @Inserts=concat("select concat('insert into ", in_db,".",tablename," values(',concat_ws(',',",@Sels,"),');')
 as MyColumn from ", in_db,".",tablename, " where ", in_ColumnName, " = " , in_ColumnValue, " group by ",@Whrs, ";");

 PREPARE Inserts FROM @Inserts;

 EXECUTE Inserts;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Adding this in connection settings did the trick :

respect binary flags=false;

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adding this in connection settings did the trick : respect binary flags=false;

Comment: I ran into a similar issue with retrieving dataset row values.  The field affected was a DateTime field and would only return System.Byte[] instead of the field value.  Adding the string you mentioned solved the problem.

Comment: @Anuya +1 for that, it worked like a charm!
I also had the same problem where the DateTime field would return System.Byte[] instead of the actual date value.
What does this flag do?